# ssh key forward without ssh-add

Tags: ssh, private-key, ssh-agent

I have couple of hosts `HostA`, `HostB` and a key `KeyX` used to ssh to both the hosts. I am trying to ssh to `HostA` first and then ssh to `HostB` from `HostA`.

Following steps do not work:

```
localhost :> ssh -i KeyX HostA
hosta :> ssh -A HostB
```

SSH to `HostB` fails with error complaining about "Permission denied (publickey)."

Following steps work:

```
localhost:> ssh-add KeyX
localhost:> ssh -i KeyX HostA
hostA:> ssh -A HostB
```

Works. I understand that `ssh-add` adds key to the ssh-agent but don't understand why the first process does not works and why adding the key to the agent make a difference. Can someone explain what was required for key forward that is satisfied by ssh-add, wasn't clear from available public documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that ssh-add adds key to the ssh-agent

Yes

> but don't understand why the first process does not works and why adding the key to the agent make a difference.

The key is on your machine. If you do not add it to the agent and do not forward this agent to the `hostA` (probably specified in configuration?), it will not see the key and will not be able to authenticate you.

> Can someone explain what was required for key forward that is satisfied by `ssh-add`, wasn't clear from available public documents.

Use `ssh-add -l`. It will list the keys you have in your agent. At first it does not list your key, after `ssh-add` it does. You should be able to run the same command on the `hostA`, where you should see the same key forwarded from your local machine.

Comment: Thanks, your response made me realize that i was missing the difference b/w ssh key agent vs ssh client. This doc talk about the step-by-step process which helps  http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html#fwd